# Go's Echo Framework Router Issue?

Tags: go

so this might be my limited understanding of Golang, as I am still learning it. But I have built a working router function within the main package / file in my app, passing in the context and that works fine.

However when I moved this to its own package, it stoped working, I am guesting this has something to do with not passing in the context from the main package?

So this works:

```
func router(e *echo.Echo) {

  addresController := &controllers.AddressController{
      config.NewController(),
  }

  //Address Routes
  address := e.Group("/address")

  address.GET("/all", func(c echo.Context) error {
     return addresController.AddressList(c)
  })

}
```

Loading into the main func like so,

```
 func main() {
   //Build The Echo Framework
   e := echo.New()

   //Load Router Function
   router(e)

   //Start Echo Web Server
   e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":5060"))
 }
```

But when I move over to this using this in the main func,

```
 router.BuidlRoutes(e)
```

and putting all the address routes into the `BuildRoutes` function I get back empty results.

Thanks,

UPDATE

my `BuildRouter` function as asked for:

```
func BuidlRoutes(e *echo.Echo) {
  addresController := &controllers.AddressController{
    config.NewController(),
  }

  //Address Routes
  address := e.Group("/address")

  address.GET("/all", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return addresController.AddressList(c)
  })

  address.GET("/id/:id", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return addresController.AddressByID(c)
  })
}
```

and this is my `Address Controller Struct`

```
type AddressController struct { 
   *config.MyController
}
```

This Address Controller is loading a MyController,

```
type MyController struct {
  *DBSettings
}

func NewController() *MyController {
  return &MyController{}
}
```

Comment: Just for calrification: You moved the `func` `router` to the package `router` and renamed it to `BuildRoutes`?

Comment: yes, sorry should have stated that. All the routes were in package main in the router function. Now they are in the router package within the BuildRouter function.

Comment: Could you post your `func BuildRoutes`?

Comment: Updated the question with the func and the structs I have built

Comment: Thanks. But honestly I am baffled that this is not working. Perhaps you introduced an error somewhere else? This looks absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks - at lest my golang is getting better :) - but the only thing i did was to move the routers function into its own package and import that package into the main one. I was thinking that the context is not been set right? but not sure how / or what I have changed to result in empty data returns

Comment: Perhaps `addresController.AddressList(c)` gets (in the routes package) initialized in a different way?

Comment: Ok, so how can I check for that? I have no unit testing done in this system let (thats still on the learning path for me with Go)

Comment: doh!! Sorry this is all my fault. Should look closer at my setup 1st! - I removed the old database a recreated it, once I move the code around a bit. In doing so I removed all the data! I think I need some better checks in place but it does all work! - Many thanks for your help!